# How to connect socket via external IP (Mac )

Tags: c, sockets, ip, port, external

My question is, how to connect to socket on romote mechine? 
I can only connect sockets on same network..

I wrote a simple code (in c), that simulate a server (open socket and listen for client). in Mac.

I'm trying to connect this socket as a client from iPhone (with simple objectiv-c code).

If my internet on both, server and client, is on the same network (WiFi) and in client I trying to connect to 192.168.1.x, it's working. 
But when, in client, I'm trying to connect via external IP (with the same port) connection is failed.

I never did this bofore. Maybe I miss somthing.. I've tried to turn my FireWall off. It did not help.

Thanks.

Edit: If it's not clear.. my Mac is connected by router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a setting like this, the "external IP" would typically be the IP of the router. In all likelihood you'll need to configure the router to forward the relevant port to the internal IP address.

It could also be the case that for the port forwarding to work, the request has to come in on the external (WAN) interface. This depends on how the router is configured. If that's the case, you'll need to make sure that you're accessing the external IP via the cellular network and not the Wi-Fi connection on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to your server via a local IP address (i.e., you're connecting to another machine on the same local router via a delegated DHCP address), then your issue is on the network, not the IP-stack of the local machine.

You'll need to look into your router settings ... many routers will block a number of services, especially those on custom ports, in order to prevent malicious attacks from sources external to the local network.

Comment: In my router, it's called "Forwarding".